# Restore deleted Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) partition

Tags: partitioning, encryption, data-recovery, partition-recovery

I've deleted an external HDD via OS X disk utility and created a new Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted) partition but didn't write any data to it.
The password differs from the deleted Partion (was Mac OS Extended (Journaled, Encrypted).

However I do know the password of the old partition!

Is there any chance to restore pictures from that drive? I've found this tool http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk
but I think it can't handle encrypted Partitions?

Comment: Nothing can handle encrypted partitions, that's the entire idea of encryption.

Comment: The idea of encryption is that no one can handle it without the right password. And I know the password for the deleted partion!

Comment: ... but you don't have the other half of the key... the directory structure